# How to show checksum in kendo barcode?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I tried this helper:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Barcode()
      .Name("token")
      .Encoding(BarcodeSymbology.EAN13)
      .Checksum(true) //Nothing changes if true or false
      .Value(Model.Ean13Code)
)
```

Since nothing changed, I tried to use Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var barcode = $('#token').data('kendoBarcode');
    barcode.setOptions({
        checksum: true
    });
});
```

Still without checksum.

I also tried to set the value 13 digit with checksum, but an exception occured, it should only be 12 digit.

What I am missing?

[image: Barcode]

Comment: the code is correct but could you please provide referenced kendo DLL and JS version detail?

Comment: I use `v2016.2.504` @JayeshGoyani. I thought the problem is in my end. I will try to upgrade to the latest build tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Barcode's MVC wrapper. The default value of the `checksum` property in the JavaScript code is `false`. However, the C# code implies the default value is `true`. As a result, when you set `.Checksum(true)`, nothing is serialized to the client, so `false` is assumed.

A possible workaround is to change the client-side prototype before the widget instance is initialized:

```
<script>

    $(function () {
        kendo.dataviz.ui.Barcode.fn.options.checksum = true;
    });

</script>

@(Html.Kendo().Barcode()
      .Name("token")
      .Encoding(BarcodeSymbology.EAN13)
      .Checksum(true)
      .Value("123456789012")
)
```

You will still need `.Checksum(true)` in the server-side declaration, otherwise `false` will be serialized, which will override the default client-side value, no matter what that is.